# Undefined method `build_for` for class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple app in which I want to allow the admin to create a new company. My create method in the controller is as follows:

```
def create
    @company = Company.find_by({ name: company_create_params[:company_name] })

    if @company.nil?
        @company = Company.build_for(company_create_params)
    else
        return render :status => 200, :json => {
                :error => true,
                :reason => 'This company already exists in the database!'
        }
    end

    if @company.save
        return render :status => 200, :json => {
                :success => true
        }
    else
        return render :status => 500, :json => {
                :error => true,
                :reason => 'There was a problem adding the company'
        }
    end
end

private

def company_create_params
    params.require(:company).permit( :company_name, :company_total_credits )
end
```

And my company model is:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :role
end
```

But every time I make an API post it gives me an error `Undefined method`build_for`for class #<....>`

Is it because of the `has_many` relationship? I don't want to add any value for the roles, rather I want them to be able to do it later on. Is there no way to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the whole error?, which Rails version?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Company.build(...)`?

Comment: @Gerry yes you're right. That was my bad, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesn't provide a `build_for` method, hence the error.

You probably meant `build`, which is a method defined on collection associations. In this case, you probably want `new` or `create` since `Company` is a model, not an association.

Your whole action could be reduced significantly by following some conventions, by the way:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  validates :company_name, uniqueness: true
end

# controller
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_create_params)

  if @company.save
    render json: { success: true }
  else
    render status: 500, json: {
      error: true,
      reason: @company.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    }
  end
end
```